# Why integration user deletes the assignee and triggers the assignment rules?

Tags: case, assignment-rules

i'm connected to external system that syncs data to case object.
i have an issue when sometimes the sync deletes the assignee in the case and triggers the assignment rules.

i didn't succeed to reproduce this event, neither the debug log don't show anything related (i do see that the sync occurred and in debug i see that the assignment rules are fired after some trigger, but inside this trigger we are not calling explicit to the assignment rules).

any idea how to fix it or why it happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really call the assignment rule from Apex Code during a trigger. It would seem that your integration is setting the AssignmentRuleHeader useDefaultRule to true or the assignmentRuleId (SOAP), or setting the Sforce-Auto-Assign header to true or an assignment rule ID. Presumably, your external integration system is setting one of these headers based on configuration options. Contact the provider of the external system or check that system's documentation on how to disable that feature.